# Sign up for Google AppEngine without SMS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I would like to use Google AppEngine, but it appears to require a cellphone to receive SMS for verification.

Is there any way around this, or any other option I can take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible.

> Can I create an App Engine application without an SMS verification code? Or without a mobile phone?

For now, you'll need a special code to create your first Google App Engine application. Currently, we're only sending these codes via SMS messages to mobile phones, so you'll need a mobile phone with SMS (or "Text Messages") capabilities (most phones have this) to create an application. You can verify your account by signing into the Administration Console.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I was able to receive the text message using Google Voice.
Sign up for a Google Voice account and put in the number it gives you.
Your Google Voice number is capable of receiving SMS messages.